# how to create api keys for securing google API gateway(Beta) programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, google-api-gateway

**Use case:** Users allowed to create api keys and revoke them from webapp.

The docs seem to only show creating Api keys using the Cloud Console. ([Link to docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key))

Comment: I have not used the API-KEYS REST API, but one exists in "alpha" status. The CLI has commands that should help you get started: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys/create If you enable the command line option `--log-http` when running `gcloud` you can see the APIs being called and their parameters.

Comment: @JohnHanley Alpha -> Beta, Beta -> Alpha,... I'm lost with the release life cycle of this API :) :)